# A better charmap for Windows, with string search and latest Unicode/emoji characters

Tags: windows, unicode, emoji

There's a charmap tool in Windows but it lacks certain features:

1. Search by description: it should be able to search by the description of the characters, like "back arrow" should find ← and maybe even ↰
2. It should have all the latest emoji characters like  (which should also show up when searching for "left")

Is there any charmap-like software for Windows that also fulfills these two features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html)

It's a fantastic Extended Character Map that will let you explore all of your choices in a font like Segoe UI Emoji. (src: [How to enter and use Emoji on Windows 8.1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToEnterAndUseEmojiOnWindows81.aspx))

Search by description (search isn't great (no wildcard/regex) but still...)
 Latest Emojis

[image: screenshot]