# Alternative to CharMap

Tags: windows, offline, unicode, font-utility

The Windows Character Map allows me to scroll through all the characters that exist in a particular font, either sorted strictly by codepoint number or grouped by Unicode Subrange name, and select one or more to copy. When I select a character, it does tell me the Unicode name (e.g., *Latin Small Letter C With Caron*). However, sometimes I want to “work backward”, and find a character from a full or (more often) partial Unicode name.

Is there a program for Windows that does this? At a minimum, I’d like the following characteristics:

1. Intelligent search, returning correct name and code point number - that is, if I ask for something like ***OE LIGATURE*** it should return both *U+0152 Latin Capital Ligature Oe* and *U+0153 Latin Small Ligature Oe*, or some indicator that the current font does not have a glyph at the matching code point. If the code point does exist, and the program is GUI (see below), display the matching glyph(s) suitable for copy-and-paste.
2. A normalization option - that is, if I ask for something like ***CAPITAL S WITH CARON*** with this option ON, instead of returning *U+0160 Latin Capital Letter S With Caron*, it would return *U+0053 Latin Capital Letter S + U+030C Combining Caron*, or some indication that one of the needed glyphs (probably the combining diacritic) is missing from the current font.

The following would be nice to have, but not essential:

1. Maintain a database of which codepoints are available in which fonts, and on a query, indicate which font(s) have glyphs at the requested code points. Given the unreasonably large number of fonts available on my system, it would be acceptable if it only indexes the fonts that I’ve actually searched at least once.
2. A normalization function - if I paste a string into an input text field, and it has characters with diacritics included, an output text field will have the string with the diacriticalized characters converted to non-diacriticalized characters plus the appropriate combining diacritic.
3. Both GUI and console interfaces. If this is not an option, prefer GUI over console, to support copy-and-paste and the normalization functions.

Gratis and Libre are preferred, but not required; the lower the cost for a program that's not gratis, the happier I will be.

Web-based is not acceptable; I do too much work off-line.

Periodic relicensing to keep the program functional is a deal-killer. I don’t mind paying for periodic updates (if, for example, the Unicode Consortium defines a new set of language code points), but I don’t want it to STOP working just because I didn't pay $X this year.

Comment: Not offline, but maybe helpful also for other readers: http://shapecatcher.com/ and https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html I wish that was available offline

Comment: Did you see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/a-better-charmap-for-windows-with-string-search-and-latest-unicode-emoji-charac?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Wow! Those 2 web-based tools you posted are amazing! Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasWeller - I'm looking at BabelMap as I write this; I haven't decided that it's a good answer, but I encourage you to propose it - or the combination of it and BabelPad - as an Answer to this question anyway. The combination of BabelMap and BabelPad from that source may well turn out to be an acceptable answer, even if B'Map alone isn't.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - Those web utils are not what I need, but are nevertheless interesting and useful. Thank you!

Comment: I've never used it myself. If you think you found a solution, you can self-answer this question.